# How can I create a partial proxy class from large WSDL?

Tags: c#, .net, wsdl.exe

I have a large WSDL file from a third party service provider.

Is there any way to cherry pick what services, contracts, endpoints I want
when I use the wsdl tool command line?

Visual Studio crashesh because of the volume of services included in the wsdl.

***Update***
Seems like this is not possible. Just need to edit the wsdl to contain only relevant contracts. Third party provided solved the issue.

Comment: Are you married to classic web services or is WCF an option? `svcutil` is marginally more stable than `wsdl` (though it can't handle all constructs). If that fails as well, one option is to download the WSDL and then filter it client side (after all, it's "just" XML, albeit spectacularly involved XML). I'm not familiar with any existing tools that specialize in this for WSDL, though they probably exist.

Comment: Thank you. The provided just supplied us with updated xml.

Answer (score 1):

**Precompile your service references into a separate class library.**

- Create a new class library project
- Add service reference to all needed WSDLs
- Compile project
- Grab dll from class library project and add as a file reference to the project where you want reference the services.

***Disclaimer:***
*I know this doesn't specifically answer your question, but it should solve your root problem, which is Visual Studio running slow or crashing when you reference code generated from your WSDL. If Visual Studio is crashing at the time of the when you are adding the service reference, this may not help you. In that case, I apologize.*